# Can't display data labels in chartJS

Tags: asp.net-core, chart.js

I have a web app written with ASP .NET Core, on one of the pages there is a bar chart created using chartJS (it gets data from database). I'm trying to display data values over each bar in the chart. I tried using [this plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels), but then my chart doesn't show on the page and I'm getting the following errors: **Uncaught ReferenceError: ChartDataLabels is not defined** and **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'datalabels' of undefined**:[image]

Here is my code for the chart:

```
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.3.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@1.0.0"></script>
            <div>
                <canvas id="workTSChart_MTK"></canvas>
            </div>                
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Get",
                        url: '@Url.Action("OnGetWorkTSData_MTK","home")',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            var data = response.hrPlan;
                            var data2 = response.hrReestr;
                            var data3 = response.hrFact;

                            console.log("hrPlan=" + response.hrPlan);
                            console.log("hrSub=" + response.hrReestr);
                            console.log("hrFact=" + response.hrFact);

                            var ctx = document.getElementById("workTSChart_MTK");
                            var workTSChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                                plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
                                type: 'bar',
                                data: {
                                    labels: [
                                        'ООО "МТК"',
                                    ],
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Plan',
                                        data: [response.hrPlan],
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(161, 221, 239)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(161, 221, 239)',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'Sub',
                                        data: [data2],
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(254, 171, 133)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(254, 171, 133)',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'Fact',
                                        data: [data3],
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(127, 137, 138)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(127, 137, 138)',
                                    }]
                                },
                                options: {
                                    responsive: true,
                                    scales: {
                                        y: {
                                            max: 600000,
                                            min: 500000,
                                            ticks: {
                                                stepSize: 10000,
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    plugins: {
                                        datalabels: {
                                            color: '#000000',
                                            display: true,
                                        },
                                        legend: {
                                            position: 'top',
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                            display: true,
                                            text: 'Sample title'
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                            });

                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                            console.log("This is ERROR line");
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**
I've updated my code thanks to **@LeeLenalee**'s advice, but now I'm getting another error message: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined**
[image]

Updated code:

```
            <div>
                <canvas id="workTSChart_MTK"></canvas>
            </div>                      
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@1.0.0"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Get",
                        url: '@Url.Action("OnGetWorkTSData_MTK","home")',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            var data = response.hrPlan;
                            var data2 = response.hrReestr;
                            var data3 = response.hrFact;
                            
                            console.log("hrPlan=" + response.hrPlan);
                            console.log("hrSub=" + response.hrReestr);
                            console.log("hrFact=" + response.hrFact);

                            var ctx = document.getElementById("workTSChart_MTK");
                            var workTSChart = new Chart(ctx, {  
                                plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
                                type: 'bar',
                                data: {
                                    labels: [
                                        'ООО "МТК"',
                                    ],
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Plan',
                                        data: [response.hrPlan],
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(161, 221, 239)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(161, 221, 239)',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'Sub',
                                        data: [data2],
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(254, 171, 133)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(254, 171, 133)',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'Hour',
                                        data: [data3],
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(127, 137, 138)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(127, 137, 138)',
                                    }]
                                },
                                options: {
                                    responsive: true,
                                    scales: {
                                        y: {
                                            max: 600000,
                                            min: 500000,
                                            ticks: {
                                                stepSize: 10000,
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    plugins: {
                                        datalabels: {
                                            color: '#000000',
                                            display: true,
                                        },
                                        legend: {
                                            position: 'top',
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                            display: true,
                                            text: 'Sample title'
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                            });

                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                            console.log("This is ERROR line");
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
As it turns out, there is an updated version of chartjs-plugin-datalabels that is working with ChartJS 3.0, so the solution was to implement latest versions of both as shown below:

```
<body>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.5.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>        
</body>
```

Comment: After 3 days finally I found the solution for this problem in your UPDATE 2 - THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/) you will need to have at least Chart.js version 2.7.0 installed, you are currently using 2.3.0.

After that you either have to register the plugin globally by calling `Chart.plugins.register(ChartDataLabels);` so all the charts have the datalabels or register it locally to the chart you want the labels for as shown in the example below:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@1.0.0"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've done as you described but now I'm getting this error message: `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined`. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: No, not without any context

Comment: I dont exectly know where the issue is comming from but I suspect it might have something to do with that your are trying to use V3 sytanx while using V2, for the V2 documentation you can go here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. I have data in brackets, like that: `data: [data2]`. When I remove those brackets, error disappears and chart does show, but with no values in it. I'll experiment with it some more to find the issue.

Comment: @witchgen Is there any progress sir? If there's any further issue on this case?

Comment: @Tiny Wang Unfortunately, I'm still trying to resolve this issue. Do you have a similar problem? If so, I will update my post if I find the solution.

Comment: @witchgen Thanks for reply and I copied your updated code snippet to run in my side, and it really worked well, I deleted ajax request part while using mock data instead. So it more likely that the data you obtained from the server lead to the issue. And as you said above that after removing those brackets error disappear. So I think here we need to check the response and format the data. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufkdR.png

Comment: I found the solution, it was to use the latest versions of both Chartjs and datalabels plugin. I've updated my post to reflect that.